# DOM Event target destructuring

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to destructure the innerHTML property off an event target, but the DOM doesn't seem to update when it's done this way. It works with styling, but not with innerHTML reassignment.

```
heading = document.querySelector('h1');

heading.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    let {innerHTML} = e.target;
    innerHTML = "Hi there";
})
```

Comment: `innerHTML` is first a DOM node, but then you assign a string to the variable, instead of to a property of that Node. What you probably *meant* to do was: `innerHTML.innerHTML = “Hi there”` (but obviously your variable name should be revised for the purpose of being less confusing).

Comment: okay, I understand it being a DOM node, but I don't understand the innerHTML.innerHTML part you're describing

Answer (score 2):

Using destructuring like that is the equvalent of this:

```
heading.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    let foo = e.target.innerHTML;
    foo = "Hi there";
})
```

In this case, because innerHTML is not an object, but is instead a scalar, JavaScript will do a copy by value, not by reference. Which means that changing `foo` does *not* change `e.target.innerHTML` because they are not pointing to the same location in memory.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Guess I'll have to stick with my ugly "e.target.innerHTML" line then.

Comment: You *can* pull out the target and it will work, like `const { target } = e;` which makes it a little better. This works because target is an object, and will be copied by reference, so any changes you make to it are made to the actual dom object.